# Glassfish - log System.err to second location or do something after logrotate

Tags: linux, logging, java, glassfish, log-rotation

we have a GF4 server that produces a lot of logs. Currently it is setup like this:

```
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.excludeFields   <>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file    <${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency  <1>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter       <com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole    <false>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles <25>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.multiLineMode   <true>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours    <0>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes    <104857600>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange    <true>
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes      <0>
handlerServices <com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler>
```

This is working fine. But we would like to keep everything that gets logged to System.err for a longer time.

1. Is there a possibility to log everything to server.log and additionally everything in System.err to another file?
2. Is there a possibility to hook into the rotation to do something after the file rotated (e.g. filter the file).